# How to: Updating TreeView MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, treeview

I have a treeview, which shows files and folders beginning at a "project root" (C:\Banana)

If a file or folder gets added inside the root, i want it to show up in my treeview

```
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ExplorerRoot}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Model:FolderItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Caption}"></TextBlock>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type IO:FileInfo}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Tag="{Binding FullName}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>

public class FolderItem
{
    public DirectoryInfo Info { get; set; }

    public FolderItem(DirectoryInfo info)
    {
        Info = info;
    }

    public FolderItem(string path) : this(new DirectoryInfo(path)) {}

    public string Caption
    {
        get { return Info.Name; }
    }

    public IList Children
    {
        get
        {
            var children = new CompositeCollection();
            var subdir = Info.GetDirectories().Select(info => new FolderItem(info)).ToList();
            children.Add(new CollectionContainer { Collection = subdir });
            children.Add(new CollectionContainer { Collection = Info.GetFiles() });
            return children;
        }
    } 
}
```

In ViewModel on OpeProjectCommand

```
 ExplorerRoot = new ObservableCollection<FolderItem> { new FolderItem(_project) };
 OnPropertyChanged("ExplorerRoot");
```

I have tried a couple different routes so far including adding a timer to FolderItem which on Elapsed would call OnPropertyChanged("Children"), but this caused the nodes to constantly collapse since they were being rebuilt. I also tried to hook up a binding between an IsExpanded bool added to FolderItem and the event but couldn't seem to get the binding correct. I also started down a path to add a FileSystemWatcher but stopped as I didn't have a good way to update the ExplorerRoot.

For the moment I have simply implemented a "refresh" button which just rebinds ExplorerRoot. I am ok with this for the most part, the biggest issue is the user then has to re-expand all subfolders.

I feel like I'm possibly missing something obvious as this would seem like a common requirement.

I am open to ideas and changing my structure.

Answer (score 0):

Your Children property returns a new collection every time the get is called. This is typically bad practice and is probably not going to work well for your scenario. Create a field and return that instead.